# Magento2.3 - Many Magento core modules are disabled when deploying on test sites

Tags: magento2, magento2-3-3

I recently upgraded my site from `Magento2.2.3` to `2.3.3`.

As everyone knows, when upgrading, Inventory module will be disabled, but when I checked, many other modules are disabled, even though I use `config.php.dist` to enable the module, but I did not disabled them.  Has anyone ever encountered this case?

**List Module:**

```
Magento_AdminAnalytics
Magento_AmqpStore
Magento_AuthorizenetGraphQl
Magento_BraintreeGraphQl
Magento_GraphQl
Magento_EavGraphQl
Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl
Magento_CatalogPageBuilderAnalytics
Magento_CatalogPageBuilderAnalyticsStaging
Magento_StoreGraphQl
Magento_CardinalCommerce
Magento_CheckoutAddressSearch
Magento_CheckoutAgreementsGraphQl
Magento_CmsGraphQl
Magento_CmsPageBuilderAnalytics
Magento_CmsPageBuilderAnalyticsStaging
Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_CatalogGraphQl
Magento_CustomerBalanceGraphQl
Magento_CustomerGraphQl
Magento_DirectoryGraphQl
Magento_DownloadableGraphQl
Magento_BundleGraphQl
Magento_QuoteGraphQl
Magento_GiftCardGraphQl
Magento_GoogleShoppingAds
Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_GraphQlCache
Magento_GroupedCatalogInventory
Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl
Magento_AuthorizenetAcceptjs
Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct
Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct
Magento_PaypalGraphQl
Magento_BannerPageBuilderAnalytics
Magento_GiftCardAccountGraphQl
Magento_RelatedProductGraphQl
Magento_RewardGraphQl
Magento_RmaGraphQl
Magento_SalesGraphQl
Magento_BannerPageBuilder
Magento_Elasticsearch6
Magento_SendFriendGraphQl
Magento_StagingPageBuilder
Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl
Magento_SwaggerWebapi
Magento_SwaggerWebapiAsync
Magento_SwatchesGraphQl
Magento_CatalogStagingPageBuilder
Magento_TaxGraphQl
Magento_CheckoutAddressSearchGiftRegistry
Magento_ThemeGraphQl
Magento_Tinymce3
Magento_Tinymce3Banner
Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_AuthorizenetCardinal
Magento_VaultGraphQl
Magento_WebapiAsync
Magento_ElasticsearchCatalogPermissions
Magento_WeeeGraphQl
Magento_PageBuilderAnalytics
Magento_WishlistGraphQl
```